# iOS SK Particle Emitter Money rain animation

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to make a money rain animation, but i want to use multiple sprites that change during the time. Is is possible to do it with Particle Emitter or do i need to make a bunch of objects fall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SKEmitterNode` can do exactly what you need. Take a look at its properties [in the apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/).

However, keep in mind that the sprites created by the particle emitter are kept private so you can't access them directly. Nevertheless, if you want to change the sprites after they are created you can do that through something like this for example:

```
SampleEmitterNode.particleAction = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:1], [SKAction setTexture:someTexture]]];
```

This would change all the particle sprites of the emitter node to have a new texture after 1 second. You could do whatever you'd like with the sprites using the `particleAction`, just you have to specify it beforehand.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

You can created multiple objects of `SKEmitterNode` and control their lifetime, particle number or reset the simulation.